# angular mat-select with ngModel binding opens dropdown at bottom of the screen

Tags: angular, mat-datepicker, mat-select

The below select element works fine.

```
<select name="state" #state="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.empFormData.state">

     <option value="" selected></option>
     <option value="ALABAMA">ALABAMA</option>
     <option value="ALASKA">ALASKA</option>
     <option value="ARIZONA">ARIZONA</option>

</select>
```

When this is changed to

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">

   <mat-select name="state" #state="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.empFormData.state" >
     <mat-option value="" selected></mat-option>
     <mat-option value="ALABAMA">ALABAMA</mat-option>
     <mat-option value="ALASKA">ALASKA</mat-option>
     <mat-option value="ARIZONA">ARIZONA</mat-option>
   </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>
```

the dropdown opens up at the bottom of the screen.This happens with mat-datepicker too.Anybody have an idea on this

Comment: include the material css into your style.css file

Comment: yes...adding the below statement @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; solved theissue. Wont this css be added when installing angular/material itself. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the material css into your style.css file

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
```